# Networking in Android

Tags: java, android, networking

I know in Android you can do networking and I've done it but I've only been able to do it when the phone is connected to a WiFi network. I'm wondering if is there a way for my Activity to connect to my server without having an active WiFi connection.

It would kind of be a pain to market my game if you must be connected to a WiFi network in order to play with other people. When I tried connecting to my server without an active WiFi connection i get this error:

```
java.net.SocketException: No route to host
```

All answers are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make network calls and use network resources, you need to be connected to a network: either with "cellular" data, such as 3G or EDGE, or WiFi.

However, Android should handle most this behavior pretty well behind the scenes.

For more information, check out Android's [Connectivity Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html), [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html), and Java's [Sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).

Comment: Hey thanks for answering, sorry it took so long for me to look at it.

Comment: By the way my computer had a firewall on it so when i connected to it through the wifi it worked because it was on the same local network but once i tried it withought the wifi it was being blocked by the firewall.